# Imagick appears installed, but class is not found

Tags: php, imagick

I'm trying to use Imagick in my php script on my website.
The host says that it is pre-installed and indeed when I view `phpinfo()` it shows that imagick 3.1.2 is installed. But when I try to use it in the script it says

> Fatal error: Class 'Imagick' not found in

What should I do, to be able to use ImageMagick?

Btw, I don't have admin privileges, so can't really install anything.